# AWS cognito logging out with Streamlit (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, streamlit

I built a simple application using Streamlit (python) and AWS Cognito. I managed to set up a user pool and access to the application through an application load balancer and Fargate.

However, although logging in is no problem, I'm struggling trying to figure out how to actually log out. I found the following documentation: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html`. I assumed that entering `https://<my-application>.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/logout?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&logout_uri=https://myclient/logout/` in the address bar would result in a logout, but I just get a 404 response?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to register the logout URL in the User Pool Client settings, just like you have to register the login callback URL. Have you done that?

Comment: Hi @MarkB, thanks for your reply.
I added a general URL in that field indeed (https://google.com), but would ideally like this to just go back to the Cognito login screen. Am I supposed to use a different address call to do the logout?

Comment: You need the logout_uri to go back to your application. From there you could have your application immediately trigger the login process again if you want, that's entirely up to how you configure your application.

Comment: @MarkB I think that is the part that is not entirely clear to me. As the application is just a single page in which a dashboard runs using Streamlit, what should the logout_uri be? Is this just the DNS address of the load balancer?

Comment: Yes the DNS address of the load balancer I guess. I don't know anything about Streamlit, but I assume if it's a Python webapp you should be able to detect that the user isn't logged in, and initiate the Cognito login process.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I tried it by replacing the logout_uri in the address above, after inserting it in the callback URL, but this still results in a 404 error.

Comment: Hi @Stijn, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hi @Quintin unfortunately not. Although I would still like to find a solution to this in case you would have any suggestions or advice.